# My goal is to print random items in my list (uppercase). After printing the item, how do I then remove that item from my list so it cant repeat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here is part of my code:

```py
i = int(input("length of speech: "  ))
b = 0

while b < i:
       print(random.choice(uppercase)+ " ", end = "")      
       b += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely have the right idea if you want to do this with a loop.

```py
uppercase = [...] # your list goes here

while len(uppercase) > 0:
    i = random.randint(0, len(uppercase)) # Pick a random index in the list
    print(uppercase[i]) # Print out the corresponding element
    del uppercase[i] # Delete the element from the list and start again
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `random.sample`, which samples without replacement:

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Since `random.sample` takes the number of draws as an input, you would draw all `i` letters at the same time, i.e. you don't use the loop anymore. This also makes things more "pythonic", as some call it.

Putting everything together, your example would look like this:

```
import random
import string

uppercase = string.ascii_uppercase

i = int(input("length of speech: "  ))

print(" ".join(random.sample(uppercase, i)))
```

Note that this throws an error if `i` is larger than the length of uppercase, as it should.